# HTTP error when uploading an image using default Flash Uploader in Wordpress

Tags: image, wordpress, upload

I am getting an HTTP error while uploading an image using the flash uploader, for all users except the admin user. The error is occuring even with users that have administrative priviledges.

Since the admin user does not get an error I doubt is would be a directory security issue - nevertheless I recusively chmoded the uploads directory to 777.

To make things even more strange, I have another blog, using the same plugins and template (through symbolic links) where all authors can upload new images.

The files from both blogs are identical, except for the wp-config that contains different DB and language settings. The blog giving the error in set to fr_FR i18n.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

This still sounds like a permissions issue. Let me ask you this, what type of hosting environment do you have? Shared, dedicated, semi-dedicated? Sometimes the shared environment blocks you from actually changing the chmod permissions. If you do have the ability to successfully change permissions, chmod 777 for your uploads directory should work, unless your public/php user is impersonating another user account. Could this be the case?

Are the environments the same between both blogs?

What is the error code/message you get when trying to upload with a user other than the admin?

Do you have your uploads directory set properly in your miscellaneous settings? If so, can you view these images at their direct location after uploading them with the admin account?

Sorry pose more questions, but I think it will help narrow it down a little more.

Acorn